# how to use "for" for open file from menu design from listview android

Tags: android, listview, for-loop

I used listview to show chapter of story and I have second activity with a webview to show content of chapter store in `file.html`.

Now, my story have 1000 chapters, I can't use `if position = xx` for every chapter in `setOnItemClick` to call file `xx.html` and show it on second activity with webview.

eg:

```
lvSinhVien.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position == 1)
            {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if(position == 2)
            {

               ......
            }
```

And `secondactivity.class`

```
public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file01.html");
```

can u help me do this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question it self. Pass position as extra and get it in second activity. Like this :

```
lvSinhVien.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class); 
            myIntent.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
```

And secondactivity.class

```
public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

    String str = String.valueOf(position);

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file"+String.format("%02d",str)+".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read about [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)):

```
public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_CHAPTER = "extra_chapter";

    WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);

        int chapter = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_CHAPTER, 0) : 0;
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file" + (chapter < 10 ? "0" : "") + chapter + ".html");
    }
}
```

in your first activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra(secondactivity.EXTRA_CHAPTER, position);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    lvSinhVien.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);                                       
                    newIntent.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
    }
```

and in secondactivity.class

Use position value as

```
  public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bucketno");
        //now use this position value here to show your desired file 
    }
    }
```